# Automatic dirty checks on objects using Spring data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a table and whenever something is set dirty in the table, I have to print audit logs/intercept. I am trying to use hibernate interceptors to achieve this.

The classes to note are the following:

Entity class

```
@Table(name = "SAMPLE_TABLE")
public class SampleTable extends Model {

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    String firstName;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    String city;
}
```

Update method in service class:

```
 public void updateSampleData(String id, String firstName, String city) {
    SampleTable sampleTable = sampleTableRepository.findById(id);
    sampleTable.setFirstName(firstName);
    sampleTable.setCity(city);
    sampleTableRepository.save(sampleTable);
}
```

Interceptor class:

```
    public class ApiInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    // This method is called when SampleTable object gets updated.
    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,
            Serializable id,
            Object[] currentState,
            Object[] previousState,
            String[] propertyNames,
            Type[] types) {
        if (entity instanceof SampleTable) {
            System.out.println("Update Operation");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // called before commit into database
    @Override
    public void preFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        System.out.println("preFlush");
    }

    // called after committed into database
    @Override
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        System.out.println("postFlush");
    }

}
```

But, whenever I am making data dirty in the `SAMPLE_TABLE` table, the interceptor is not getting invoked.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not Hibernate Envers?

Comment: Neil, I have edited the question. I want to invoke the interceptor or print in the console whenever an object becomes dirty.

Comment: Hibernate Envers are overkill here and it comes with a price.

Comment: Show the configuration for your Interceptor.